# Orthogonalization of a linearly independent set

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and let $S$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$. There exists an inner product $p:V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the same $S$ is a $p$-orthogonal set?

I know that the answer is yes if $S$ is finite and I know how to prove it. But I don't know the case $S$ is infinite.

Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that, even for the finite case, you need to assume that an inner product already exist.

Comment: @SolidSnake No, the claim is that one can define an inner product with this property. In the finite-dimensional case, this is equivalent to finding a symmetric matrix $A$ such that $S^TAS$ is diagonal, where $S=\begin{bmatrix}S_1&S_2&\cdots\end{bmatrix}$, the matrix with the given vectors as its columns.

Comment: @amd Exactly, but at first, it must be a finite-dimensional **normed space**, for example

Comment: @SolidSnake there exist inner product spaces that are not complete (i.e. are not Hilbert spaces)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, sorry, I realized that just after I wrote the comment

Comment: @Gustavo do we assume any sort of topology on the space $V$, or is $p$ allowed to induce an arbitrary topology?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am not assuming a fixed topology, norm or inner product, but you can build one if it is useful to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, certainly as long as we accept the axiom of choice.

Let $S = \{v_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be a linearly independent subset.  Then, by the axiom of choice, we may take a (Hamel) basis $\{v_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J}$ of $V$ where $I \subset J$.

In order to define a bilinear map $p: V \times V \to \Bbb R$, it suffices to state how it acts on a basis of $V$.  We may therefore impose the conditions
$$
p(v_{\alpha},v_{\beta}) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \alpha = \beta\\
0 & \alpha \neq \beta
\end{cases} \quad \alpha, \beta \in J
$$
The set $S$ is now $p$-orthogonal.

Comment: Of course! The generalization of the dot product. This was a foolish question. Sorry. PS: you mean a BILINEAR map.

Comment: Every question seems foolish once you've understood the answer.  Note that the axiom of choice was essential to the construction of the map; there are probably consistent systems in which an $S$ can be chosen with no corresponding $p$.

Comment: Note also that in $V$ as we've defined it here, infinite sums are not generally possible.  Even if we add that structure (say, by taking the "completion" of $V$ in some sense) we can't guarantee that $p$ behaves as expected with respect to such inputs.  Of course, one may want to take the completion with respect to the topology *induced* by this inner product.  $p$ *would* behave as expected over the resulting Hilbert space.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.